# Embedding a Join within a case in a select statement (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried this scenario a number of ways, and cannot get the syntax correct, in order to maximize the results. (sorry but this is on a SQL 2000 server)

I'd upgrade except the application may break that's running against it. 
So, I am trying to pull the maximum number of results, based on (if a case is closed). However i don't want "only" the innerjoin cases, when attempting to

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE.CASENUM      AS Case#, 
                CASE.Lastname     AS [Client Name], 
                event.actiondate  AS [Last Action in Event], 
                event.description AS [Last Event], 
                CASE.statcode     AS [Case Status], 
                transmdf.amount, 
                transmdf.postdate [Last ActionDate], 
                transmdf.description AS [Last Fin. Action] 
FROM            Transmdf 
INNER JOIN 
                ( 
                         SELECT   CASENUM, 
                                  MAX(postdate) AS latest 
                         FROM     Transmdf 
                         GROUP BY CASENUM) YYY 
ON              transmdf.CASENUM = YYY.CASENUM 
AND             transmdf.postdate = YYY.latest 
INNER JOIN      event 
ON              transmdf.casenum = event.casenum 
INNER JOIN 
                ( 
                         SELECT   CASENUM, 
                                  MAX(actiondate) AS latest 
                         FROM     EVENT 
                         GROUP BY CASENUM) XXX 
ON              EVENT.CASENUM = XXX.CASENUM 
AND             EVENT.ACTIONDATE = XXX.latest 
INNER JOIN 
                CASE 
                                ON              transmdf.casenum = CASE.casenum 
                                WHERE           CASE.statcode = 'c' 
                                ORDER BY        CASE.lastname
```

However what i run into cuts a possible 5000 cases out of my returned results.

Ideally what i'm trying to do is pull all results for cases that are "closed" past a certain date.

There is one caviat ... of those cases returned

1. showing the Last (most recent) Action (date & description) in the Event table (for each client of the query)
2. as well as their last (most recent) financial transaction (amount/date/description) (for each client of the query)

Help??

Comment: As i'd said, .. the use of the inner join, causes me to lose a number of cases (approx 4000) as it's only looking into the "Event" or "Transmdf" tables for their exclusive entries. If i look at the case table for those that have been closed during the date range i need, there are 9000 cases returned. As soon as i enter the inner joins, it shrinks the list to about 5000 cases.

Answer (score 0):

`Case`, `description` and `Event` are all key words, so you will need to use  square brackets `[]` around these words when they are being used as Object names rather than a key word, A bad choice for object names in sql server.

```
;With [event] AS
 (
   SELECT actiondate , [description] , casenum 
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY casenum ORDER BY actiondate DESC) rn 
   FROM [event]
 ),
transmdf AS
 (
  SELECT amount, postdate , [description], CASENUM
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY casenum ORDER BY postdate DESC) rn 
  FROM Transmdf
 )
SELECT [Case].CASENUM           AS [Case] 
      ,[Case].Lastname          AS [Client Name] 
      ,[event].actiondate       AS [Last Action in Event] 
      ,[event].[description]    AS [Last Event]
      ,[Case].statcode          AS [Case Status] 
      ,transmdf.amount          AS [Amount]
      ,transmdf.postdate        AS [Last ActionDate] 
      ,transmdf.[description]   AS [Last Fin. Action]
FROM [Case] 
INNER JOIN transmdf ON transmdf.casenum = [Case].casenum  AND transmdf.rn = 1
INNER JOIN [event]  ON transmdf.casenum = [event].casenum AND [event].rn  = 1
WHERE  [Case].statcode = 'c'
ORDER BY [Case].lastname
```

Comment: attempting to use your code errored out.  showing the following problems... Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Server: Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
Server: Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: Since you have only mentioned now that you are using sql server 2000 this solution will not work for you, as it will not support CTE or Ranking functions. You should have mentioned this before that what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`case` is a reserved word, so it is a bad choice for a table name.  I think the following should be easier for SQL Server to parse.

```
SELECT distinct  case.CASENUM AS Case#, c.Lastname AS [Client Name], 
       e.actiondate as [Last Action in Event], e.description as [Last Event], 
       c.statcode as [Case Status], t.amount, t.postdate as [Last ActionDate],
       t.description as [Last Fin. Action]
FROM Transmdf t INNER JOIN
     (SELECT CASENUM, MAX(postdate) AS latest
      FROM Transmdf
      GROUP BY CASENUM
     ) YYY
     ON t.CASENUM = YYY.CASENUM AND transmdf.postdate = YYY.latest Inner join
     event e
     on t.casenum = e.casenum INNER JOIN
     (SELECT CASENUM, MAX(actiondate) AS latest
      FROM EVENT
      GROUP BY CASENUM
     ) XXX
     ON e.CASENUM = XXX.CASENUM AND e.ACTIONDATE = XXX.latest inner join
     [case] c
     on t.casenum = c.casenum
where c.statcode = 'c'
ORDER BY c.lastname;
```